# this.BackgroundImage URL

Tags: image, url, background

Can you help me please to correct this code ?

```
    LBL_Image.Text = "http://sivop.net/wallpaper/214.jpg";
this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(LBL_Image.Text);
```

Cordialy

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: this code does not work, can you help me please ?
URI formats are not supported.

Comment: Try with some other image. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sahykhd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1